# windows forms user control properties execute code when build

Tags: c#, winforms

I've a User Control on C# Windows Forms. Every time when I build the project the code on my properties are fired and the message box appear. Anyone knows why?

```
public string Name 
{
    get
    {
        if(xpto != null) 
        { 
            return mystring;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("message");
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when you build or when you run? I dont hink its possible during build.

Comment: Need more information on 'xpto'. My assumption is that you're not initializing the object and hence the message. Won't know for sure until we see all of the code.

Comment: Sure, it's possible when you build. The designer will query certain properties to construct a view of your form. What is the purpose of this code? Why are you showing a message box in the getter? Stop doing that and you solve your problem.

Comment: Hi @CarbineCoder. When I build, yes. xpto = any private attribute.

Comment: Hi @CodyGray. It´s only a sample code. In fact I don´t show a message box on attribute. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: It seems like you are using messagebox in order to test your code?
Try using breakpoints instead.
if you intend to have messagebox in your running code, then please show the context of mystring and xpto

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as though "xpto" isn't being set before the property is being called. Your code will run the "else" branch as long as "xpto" hasn't been set (or has been set to null).

This means, something in your code is calling into your property "Name", before you initialize "xpto" (or, you're setting "xpto" to null, yourself). So "xpto" will be null when "Name" is called, and, the message-box gets shown.

EDIT:
Also, if it's happening on-build, it's probably because the designer won't set "xpto", itself. Instead, it uses the properties it cares about such as "Name", "Text", etc. Therefore, when the designer calls "Name", it hasn't taken into account "xpto" before-hand and "xpto" will be null when the designer gets to the property "Name".

Comment: I realize I should have waited on some clarification in the comments, but I don't have the rep to comment yet. Sorry if this is a problem.